# Подстановка значения из сессии в запрос SQL

Tags: php

В сессии хранится значение типа профиля пользователя.
Нужно подставить это значение во все запросы SQL как условие WHERE.

Например: `WHERE userType = $_SESSION['type']`

Проблема в том, что таких запросов в проекте около сотни, у каждого свое название поля, к которому необходимо применить это условие.

Что можно упростить в этом случае?

**Обновление**

Более подробно можно сказать так:
На сайт добавляется информация из разных стран. Добавляемые записи пользователем из Австрии автоматически будут помечаться меткой страны в БД (Австрия). Допустим, пользователь из России меняет страну просмотра сайта, в сессию заносится ID выбранной страны (Австрия). Теперь россиянин, просматривая сайт, будет видеть только информацию из Австралии. Т.е. для всех запросов SQL подставляется значение: Австрия.

Comment: вангую, что если обрисовать задачу шире, появятся очень здравые и безгеморройные предложения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Автоматом это не сделать вообще никак, потому что никогда 100% обращений к БД не будут содержать в себе обращение к таблице стран, а из остальных будут 10% геморройных, к которым потребуется отдельный подход, нежели ко всем остальным. Как бы я решал эту задачу (CI не знаю, пример на Yii).

- Вводим интерфейс CountrySelectionAwareModelInterface, который состоит буквально из пары методов: `setCountryId()`, `getCountryColumnName()`, можно на расширение добавить еще `setCountryIds()`. `setCountryId()` проставляет реализующему интерфейс объекту айдишник интересующей страны, `getCountryColumnName()` гарантирует получение названия соответствующего поля в таблице.
- Реализуем этот интерфейс прямо в промежуточном классе модели, от которого будут наследоваться остальные модели.
- Реализуем поведение или фильтр в промежуточном классе, который будет подтягивать эти данные и обрабатывать запрос, добавляя в него новое условие. (в Yii, кстати, это решилось бы просто через `defautScope()`).
- То, что не взлетело, разбирается руками.

Answer (score 1):

Скорей всего, запросы идут через какую-нибудь обёртку для mysql - что-то типа `(DB::select())`. Так почему бы просто не внести всю эту логику в эту обёртку, тогда запросы не придётся переписывать, их можно будет изменять внутри обёртки. Во всяком случае я не знаю, как у вас там сделано, и могу только предполагать.

Answer (score 0):

Сделать процедуру, которая будет принимать названия поля и сессию, там отфильтровывать на неправильность сессии и возвращать, а вообще должна быть соответствующая архитектура вашего проекта, которая 100% упрощала бы вам работу.

Comment: Если к архитектуры вернуться - на будущее. Какой вариант возможен?

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, по текущему заданию ничего не сказать

Comment: Не понял Вас, ничего или нечего?

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, мы **не знаем** текущей архитектуры, чтобы говорить о будущей. Скорее всего, там подойдет какое-нибудь RBAC-решение, но говорить об этом в условихя абстрактного проекта нельзя.

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос